# How to store and access request specific data in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, api, request, akka-http

I need a mechanism to store and access request specific data in Akka HTTP. Is it possible without sending values around to each actor that is called from the route?

Let's say I want to log performance of all operations, including request id, so I'm able to search logs by request id. So when logging inside actor, it would be great to do something like Request.id.

Note that API does not implement session, since this is a specific service which runs behind main API (which is doing authentication etc).

Is there any library or built in way suitable for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want is MDC.

Comment: you can use kamon prometheus to log metrics of your interest which can be integrated with grafana or kibana.

Comment: we use Kibana, but this is more our internal loggine

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok  If I use MDC to store context info, like request id and other things, I would clear it after each request. It means I have to add a clear logic at the end of each of my more than 100 routes? Also, I need to set it up when request first comes to a route? I'll give it a try, it would remove a need for passing req id as a message parameter to actor...

Comment: Also, it seems pure MDC does not work with Actors and multithread requests. I found an alternative - Lighbend Telemetry, but is's not free. Any other suggestion?